# Why Cyrillic characters are not handled properly when sending requests using Pool of Guzzle PHP library?

Tags: php, api, guzzle, cyrillic

I am using Guzzle to send the requests to the external API end-point.

In my request there is a text query value - 'https://api_endpoint/' . '?text=' .$text

When I am sending the requests one by one:

```
$response = $client->request(
            'GET',
            ''https://api_endpoint/' . '?text=' .$text,
        );
```

it works fine for any language in the text field. However, when I first iterate another query value and create an array of the requests and then send these requests using Pool:

```
$responses = Pool::batch($client, $requests, array(
        'concurrency' => 15,
    ));
```

In this case I am getting a “bad request” from the API end-point, if the text field in the request was written in Cyrillic. If, however the text field is in latin characters, everything works fine. Same for the situation when I am sending the requests one by one.

I assume that there is some problem with encoding when Guzzle Pool is used.

How do I fix it or workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Guzzle's issue. You have to urlencode `$text` before concatenating. Do `urlencode($text)` or use Guzzle's `query` option:

```
$response = $client->request(
    'GET',
    'https://api_endpoint/',
    ['query' => ['text' => $text]],
);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Spasibo Alex for introducing this function. I would never expect Guzzle do not apply this function and one has to do it explicitly.